# how is pandas kurtosis defined?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to get kurtosis using pandas. By doing some exploration, I have

```
test_series = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5000))
test_series.kurtosis()
```

however, the output is:

```
-0.006755982906479385
```

But I think the kurtosis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) should be close to (maybe normalize over N-1 instead of N, but this does not matter here)

```
(test_series - test_series.mean()).pow(4).mean()/np.power(test_series.std(),4)
```

which is

```
2.9908543104146026
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.kurtosis.html) says the following

> Return unbiased kurtosis over requested axis using Fisher’s definition of kurtosis (kurtosis of normal == 0.0)

This is probably the [excess kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Excess_kurtosis), defined as `kurtosis - 3`.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is calculating the **UNBIASED** estimator of the excess Kurtosis. Kurtosis is the normalized 4th central moment. To find the unbiased estimators of the cumulants you need the [`k-statistics`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Statistic.html).

So the **unbiased** estimator of kurtosis is `(k4/k2**2)`

To illustrate this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(11234)
test_series = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5000))
test_series.kurtosis()
#-0.0411811269445872
```

Now we can calculate this explicitly using the `k-statistics`:

```
n = len(test_series)
S1 = test_series.pow(1).sum()
S2 = test_series.pow(2).sum()
S3 = test_series.pow(3).sum()
S4 = test_series.pow(4).sum()

# Eq (7) and (5) from the k-statistics link
k4 = (-6*S1**4 + 12*n*S1**2*S2 - 3*n*(n-1)*S2**2 -4*n*(n+1)*S1*S3 + n**2*(n+1)*S4)/(n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3))
k2 = (n*S2-S1**2)/(n*(n-1))
# k2 is the same as the N-1 variance: test_series.std(ddof=1)**2

k4/k2**2
#-0.04118112694458816
```

If you want better agreement to more decimal places, you'll need to be careful with the sums as they get rather large. But they're identical to 12 places.