# How to find skewness and kurtosis correctly in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I was wondering how to calculate skewness and kurtosis correctly in pandas.
Pandas gives some values for `skew()` and `kurtosis()` values but they seem much different from `scipy.stats` values. Which one to trust pandas or `scipy.stats`?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(100)
x = np.random.normal(size=(20))

kurtosis_scipy = stats.kurtosis(x)
kurtosis_pandas = pd.DataFrame(x).kurtosis()[0]

print(kurtosis_scipy, kurtosis_pandas)
# -0.5270409758168872
# -0.31467107631025604

skew_scipy = stats.skew(x)
skew_pandas = pd.DataFrame(x).skew()[0]

print(skew_scipy, skew_pandas)
# -0.41070929017558555
# -0.44478877631598901
```

Versions:

```
print(np.__version__, pd.__version__, scipy.__version__)
1.11.0 0.20.0 0.19.0
```

Comment: **Related**: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41890870/2336654

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276138/how-is-pandas-kurtosis-defined/50277666#50277666

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [`bias=False`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html)

```
print(
    stats.kurtosis(x, bias=False), pd.DataFrame(x).kurtosis()[0],
    stats.skew(x, bias=False), pd.DataFrame(x).skew()[0],
    sep='\n'
)

-0.31467107631025515
-0.31467107631025604
-0.4447887763159889
-0.444788776315989
```

Answer (score 4):

Pandas calculate UNBIASED estimator of the population kurtosis.
Look at the Wikipedia for formulas: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kurtosis

[image]

## Calculate kurtosis from scratch

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy

x = np.array([0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0,
              2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 999])
xbar = np.mean(x)
n = x.size
k2 = x.var(ddof=1) # default numpy is biased, ddof = 0
sum_term = ((x-xbar)**4).sum()
factor = (n+1) * n / (n-1) / (n-2) / (n-3)
second = - 3 * (n-1) * (n-1) / (n-2) / (n-3)

first = factor * sum_term / k2 / k2

G2 = first + second
G2 # 19.998428728659768
```

## Calculate kurtosis using numpy/scipy

```
scipy.stats.kurtosis(x,bias=False) # 19.998428728659757
```

## Calculate kurtosis using pandas

```
pd.DataFrame(x).kurtosis() # 19.998429
```

Similarly, you can also calculate skewness.

Comment: What are the `xbar` and `n` variables in the "from scratch" version?

Comment: @BrunoFacca `xbar` is the sample mean and `n` is the sample size. I have updated the code.